# What kind of objects can code a universe?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

Jensen proved that given $V\models\sf ZFC+GCH$, there is a class generic real $r$, such that $V[r]=L[r]$, and no cardinals are collapsed.

We know that this can be modified such that $r$ is minimal, i.e. if $x\in L[r]$, then $x\in V$ or $r\in L[x]$. And we know that we can replace "real" with "subset of $\kappa$" for some arbitrary (regular?) cardinal.

But can do better?

1. Can we code the universe into a "Prikry sequence"? (Preserving cardinals, but not cofinalities.)
2. Can we code the universe into a "Namba sequence"? (Permitting whatever cardinals need to be collapsed to be collapsed, of course.)

Of course, this is a bit open-ended, and there might be related results out there which I didn't quite mention. Those are all good and well.

Comment: Assume in $V$ there is a measurable cardinal $\kappa$
and let $U$be a normal measure over it.  Force with Prikry forcing
to add an $\omega$-sequence
$C=(\kappa_n: n<\omega)$ over $V$. 
 Force over $V[C]$ by Jensen's coding to find a generic extension 
of the form $V[C][G]=L[r]$, for soeme real $r$.
 Define a new sequence $D=(\kappa_n: n \in r)$.  Then
$V[C][G]=V[C][D]$. The key point is that having $D, C$ we can recover $r$.

Comment: Okay, can we do that without adding reals, then? (Yes, code the whole damn thing into a subset of $\omega_1$; by induction: can we do it without adding bounded subsets to $\kappa$?)

Comment: I can prove the following: suppose $\kappa$ is an inaccessible limit of measurable cardinals and let $S$ be a discrete set of measurables below $\kappa$ of size $\kappa$.     Consider the corresponding Prikry product and let $C=(C_\alpha: \alpha \in S)$ be generic for it, where each $C_\alpha$ is an $\omega$-sequence cofinal in $\alpha$. Now code everything into a subset of $\kappa$, adding no bounded subsets to $\kappa.$ We may assume the generic is some $X \subset S$. Thus $V[C][X]=L[X]$ Now one can define a new sequence $D=(D_\alpha: \alpha \in S)$ such that $V[C][X]=V[C][D]$.

Comment: I kinda get the feeling that you're selling me the same idea as before, but now instead of a real, it's a subset of an inaccessible limit of measurables. :-)

Comment: Yes, the same. The problem is that I don't see how to code a large set into a Priky sequence. Note that for example by Woodin's result, $L[C]$ satisfies CH, when $C$ is an $\omega$-sequence of ordinals. But for example, I can have $L[X]$ may fail to satisfy CH, if $X \subset \omega_2$, so in some sense, there might be some difficulty in general.

Comment: Well, I did require GCH to hold...

Comment: That was a sample. For example $X$ can first code the failure of $CH$ and then recovering it, so we have GCH, but still there can be no Prikry sequence coding it.

Comment: Of course if instead of one Prikry sequence we use two, as in my first answer, we can code any real, so by Jensen, anything. The problem is that I don't know how to code a set of size larger into two Prikry sequences, that is why in my second comment I used Prikry product forcing!!!